# What are the changes in Titan Quest Anniversary Edition

Tags: titan-quest

Titan Quest recently got an anniversary edition on Steam, which is free to people who own the original. However, the description doesn't do a very good job of telling us what's updated/changed in this new edition. I noticed there seems to be Steam Workshop support added, but is there anything else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [steam store page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/475150/):

> For its 10 year anniversary, Titan Quest will shine in new splendour.
>   This Anniversary Edition combines both Titan Quest and Titan Quest
>   Immortal Throne in one game, and has been given a massive overhaul for
>   the ultimate ARPG experience.
>
> Anniversary Edition update:
>
> - Restored and improved multiplayer functionality, including new features like a built-in voice chat and NAT resolving for best
>     multiplayer connectivity
> - Support for more resolutions, larger camera distance and scaleable UI size
> - Improved performance and general stability
> - Support for modders through new modding options and a fully integrated Steam Workshop
> - Complete balance rework with improvements to all Masteries, damage types, unique items and sets
> - Countless bug fixes and other improvements, including ten years’ worth of community fixes
> - Increased challenges and rewards for larger parties and on higher difficulty levels
> - Dozens of new heroes and bosses to encounter
> - Improved enemy and pet AI
> - Quality of life features like higher stack limits, quick item pickup, a larger stash and a speed setting
> - Reduced cheating with curbed exploits, removal of test items and mod comparison in multiplayer
> - Steam Friend Invites
> - Steam Achievements
> - Steam Trading Cards

If you are intrested in all of the changes the changelog can be found here:

http://titanquestgame.com/pcchangelog/TQ_AnniversaryEdition_FullChangelog.txt